# Is a link in Wicket IValidator's error message possible?

Tags: java, validation, wicket

Is it possible in the Wicket IValidator's error message to include a link to another page in the application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No I don't think it is. You may be able to implement your own FeedbackPanel that doesn't automatically escape html. Then you can add a plain HTML link to your page. But I wouldn't call this very wicketish and it's definitely not very maintainable.

So what you could do instead is to add a Panel/WebMarkupContainer that is  visible when the model of the FormComponent doesn't have the desired value.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to add a fragment?

Comment: Of course any `Component` will work. Just need to override `onConfigure()` and call `setVisible()`

Comment: I am a complete newby, Itried to render a fragment on a page, but have failed to do so in a stateless form and [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/6.x/guide/keepControl.html#keepControl_5)  they say "it uses a markup fragment defined in the markup file of its parent container, which can be a page or a panel" , so I am not sure.

Comment: A fragment is basically the same as a panel as it provides it's own html, but with the difference that it doesn't have it's own html file but instead is defined in another's components html file by using `<wicket:fragment wicket:id="yourId">`. If you failed to render the fragment try using a panel first and if it works move everything into a fragment.

Comment: it just does not work. I will ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried with simply calling 'setEscapeModelStrings(false);'? This should do the trick avoiding HTML escaping.